# Scroll event never fires and .scrollTop() always returns 0 because of wrapper DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically what I'm trying to do is use a on scroll event and use jquery scrollTop() while using this [off-canvas menu][1]

Here's a fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/k6hsvp1a/

Here's the code that isn't working as expected:  (The scroll event never fires and scrollTop() always returns as 0)

```
$( window ).on('scroll', function() {
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  console.log('scrolling!');
});
```

My understanding is that because the off-canvas menu uses a relatively positioned wrapper div, the scroll event never fires because $(window).scrollTop() always returns zero.

How can I make a scroll event work and use scrollTop() ?

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: scroll what? scrollTop of what? Question is far too vague. Where's your code attempt that isn't working?

Comment: Sorry guys, I added a fiddle and some clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fiddle is fiddling with the wrong container.  Check my update here:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6hsvp1a/1/

This is the difference:

```
$( '.st-content' ).on('scroll', function() {
  console.log($('.st-content').scrollTop());
  console.log('scrolling!');
});
```

Every block element can scroll independently if its contents are larger than its dimensions and set to `overflow: scroll` (or `overflow: auto` (or `overflow-y` or... you get the point)).

The scroll event then fires on the actual div that's scrolling, and doesn't bubble up to the window. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)

What's also confusing is that this `div` in particular also happens to take up the whole window, so it looks like it's the window that's scrolling.

Comment: That works! Would you mind explaining why it works on .st-content but not on window?

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround!  I expanded the answer to reply to your question.

Answer (score 7):

Debugging time... this is a little heavy handed, but worked in this scenario:

```
$("*").on('scroll', function() {
  console.log($(this));
});
```

The `"*"` applies to *all* elements.

Checked out the console:

> [div.st-content, context: div.st-content, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]

So our scroll event is being triggered by **.st-content**

```
$(".st-content").on('scroll', function() {
  console.log($(this).scrollTop());
  console.log("scrolling");
});
```

Comment: Jesus this is the only thing that worked for me in mobile view. Should be the accepted answer...great answer!